# Why is xts or quantmod coding each monday as 1?

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

Is it `quantmod::getSymbols` that's returning weird weekdays, or is it `xts::.indexwday` that's messing things up?

```
library(quantmod)
symbols <- c("SPY", "QQQ")
dfs <- lapply(1:length(symbols), 
             function(i) 
               getSymbols(symbols[i], env = NULL, auto.assign=F))
table(xts::.indexwday(dfs[[1]]))
```

This is only returning things from 0 to 4. Why does it encode a Monday as a 0?

Comment: In many parts of the World, Weeks start on Monday not Sunday.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue. If I download some data with quantmod and use `.indexwday` the results are 1 - 5 not 0-4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xts::.indexwday` follows the C99/POSIX standard to be consistent with the `POSIXlt` structure.  See the *Details* section of `?POSIXlt` for the possible values, which says:

> 'wday' 0-6 day of the week, starting on Sunday.

That doesn't explain why you see `Monday = 0`. It would help if your example were fully reproducible, and we had the output from `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Just added some reproducibility, and I will check the output of `sessionInfo` the next time I am using the computer that generated the error. Works fine on this machine, so you might be on to something